# How to check method in when in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I wrote the code below.

```
 fun check(list){ list.forEach{ when(it){
   is Int -> something()
   is String -> something()
   //is method -> ??? 
   else -> consume{it}
   }}}

inline fun consume(f: () -> Unit){ f() }
```

But I don't want to check the method in else.
Is there any way to check the method in when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can just omit the `else -> consume{it}` part. `forEach` function's signature is [as follows](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html):

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit)
```

See `action`. It takes a function with `Unit` as output. This means that you do not need to return anything (`Unit` is Java's `void` equivalent).

So, in conclusion your code can look like this:

```
fun check(list: List<*>) {
    list.forEach {
        when (it) {
            is Int -> something()
            is String -> something()
            //is method -> ???
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh i`m sorry but this is not what I wanted. I want to know how to distinguish method by using grammar like is.

Comment: What do you mean by `distinguish method`?

Comment: I put the method into an array of Any types, and I want to use that method However i don`t know there is no way to distinguish between methods.

Comment: So you want to know the type of the array? E.g. `Array<Int>` -> `Int`, `Array<Something>` -> `Something`?

Comment: I seem to have insufficient explanation.
var list: Array<Any?>? = arrayOf(1000, println(10))

Comment: Do you mean you have (e.g.) 2 functions called `something`, one accepting `Int` and one `String` (`fun something(x: Int)`, `fun something(x: String)`) and you want Kotlin to automatically decide which method to choose (depending on the list's element type)?

Comment: well i think It is not what I want. something() is not important. I wondered how to check the method with such "is Method". But it(is Method) didn't work very well. Is there another way?
Or is it wrong to put a method into an array?

Comment: I think I know what you mean. When you create a array like this `arrayOf(println(10)` it'll actually be `[Unit]`. If you want to have functions in arrays you need to do it like this `{ println(10) }`. When you create a array like this, then you'll have a array of functions. You can invoke them like this: `array[i]()` where `i` is the index (like 1,2, 10, 32)

Comment: Thank you for helping me with my poor English skills. Thanks to you, I could solve the problem well. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question, but I combined the contents of the replies and what I dealt with, and I attached the results that I was trying to do.

```
var arr = arrayOf{"String", {method()}}

 fun check(arr : Array<Any?>?){ arr.forEach{ when(it){
   is Int -> println("int")
   is String -> println("str")
   else -> @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (it as () -> Unit)()       
}}}
```

thanks